# Social, Political, and Economical in One Word?

Tags: single-word-requests

As Afro-Eurasia means Africa, Europe, and Asia, what is a similar word for social, political, and economical? Sociopolitical and socioeconomical exist, but is there a way to incorporate all 3? I find myself in need of such a word when writing history papers.

> The __________ situation of Haiti during the Haitian revolution was very dependent on France's ideals.

Comment: @Cascabel - Uh, he's asking for a combo of "social", "political", and "economic".  The three are rather tightly related, and, as he states, there are already terms for two combos.

Comment: I know of no term, but I don't muck about in socio-politico-economic circles very much.  I would not be surprised if there is a "real" term, perhaps obtained by using a different root.  (Or perhaps if you Google "socio-politico-economic" you'll find something.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage is pretty rare, but I mangaged to find (following Hotlicks suggestion):

[**socio-politico-economic**](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=CqfBBQAAQBAJ&pg=PR193&lpg=PR193&dq=socio-politico-economic%20entity%20definition&source=bl&ots=swNGnvnTr6&sig=skkzg6jRlT1EDIbgp6tVM_klvRg&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

in this following example:

> In recent years, a growing importance of socio-politico-economic regions in shaping development of the country have been observed.

-Proceedings of MAC-EMM 2014

However, I cannot find an entry in a dictionary to support the usage. I did an [ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=socio-politico-economic&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1770&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csocio%20-%20politico%20-%20economic%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsocio%20-%20politico%20-%20economic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSocio%20-%20politico%20-%20economic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSocio%20-%20Politico%20-%20Economic%3B%2Cc0), but once again, it does not seem  have a very large usage.

Where [socio-economic](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/socioeconomic) refers to social differences caused by  individual economic states, and [socio-political](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sociopolitical) refers to differences between social and political groups, **socio-politico-economic** seems to be mainly a mashup of the words.

Comment: "*I* managed to find"??  ;)

Comment: @HotLicks My, you are feeling feisty tonite, arent you? I gave you credit, but while you were typing your comments, I was already researching the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you use 'sociopolitical economy". Your specific example will read as follows:
The sociopolitical economy of Haiti during the Haitian revolution was very dependent on France's ideals.

This should be acceptable because the economy of a society refers to the economic characteristics of that Society.

Sociopolitical economy is not a commonly used term because it cannot be situated in any one branch of economics, social science or political science. It is a combination of two branches of economics namely; social economics and political economics. I did not find any definition for sociopolitical economy despite the fact that there is no country or society with a standalone economy. Every country has a sociopolitical economy. I therefore define sociopolitical economy as the resultant economy produced by the interplay of social, political and economic factors in a society.

Comment: Why did you choose "sociopolitical economy" as the 'right' term?